# How do I split a git repo off of another git repo, and manage it separately?

Tags: git

I have a program that I am tracking using a git repository.  There is a bit of functionality that I would like to encapsulate and use in other projects.  I am wondering how can I create a new git repository that tracks a few files inside of a project that already has a git repository?

Also, the first git repository is tracked on Git hub.  How should I manage these two new repositories?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [git sub modules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) for this.
Your common code should be a git repo in itself. That can be a sub-module of other git repos.

However, I would recommend doing this.

Create a lib out of the common code and create its own builds with versions. The other projects should then depend on this library.

The pro of this is that this common code can move independently as the output libs are versions and dependent apps use specific versions and upgrade as required.

The con of this that you need to have CI and artifact/lib repos in place to be able to set this up.

Example:
Say I have certain String based Parsing utilities that I want to make common across various apps. And these apps are java and maven based.
So what can be done, is creating a small repo with artifact org.test/StringUtils.
Setup a job in a CI server that monitors this Git repo and builds and pushes the versions of this artifact to a repo (Say nexus or artifactory).

Dependent apps in their pom depend on this artifact just like any other thrid party library.